# a/b c/b d/r steps to follow

Tags: number-theory

.

my steps assume $d=2$ and $n=1$, then $2$ divides $1 = 1/2$
         if d does not divide $(n +1)$ then $2/1+1 = 1$
                              $1/2$ is not equal to $1$
                              hence it is false!

Comment: I don't quite understand your logic, however $2$ most definitely does not divide $1$.

Comment: Read the statement if  d divides n, so i assume d=2 and n=1, as a counter example

Comment: I'm not sure if my steps are correct, please help

Comment: But how is this a counterexample? You start with a statement that takes $d$ divides $n$ as a conditional, and now you are drawing a counterexample for the statement by violating the conditional. That's not a counterexample. You need to use a valid conditional and show the statement does not hold true.

Comment: Also, the statement happens to be true, so your steps must be false.

Comment: Let d, n ∈ N. If d divides n and d > 1, then d does not divides (n + 1), if true then prove, if false give counter example. I have to prove if statement is true or false

Comment: To be sure: These questions talk about dividing in $\mathbb{N}$, thus all the elements you use must be in $\mathbb{N}$.

We say 2 does not divide 1 in $\mathbb{N}$, since $1/2\not\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d$ divide $n$.

Therefore, for some natural $c$, $n=cd$.

Assume $d$ also divides $n+1$, and therefore, for some natural $f$, $n+1=fd$.

Since $n+1>n$ it follows $f>c$ so $f=c+g$ for some natural $g$.

From this it follows $n+1=d(c+g)=cd+gd$.

However $cd=n$ so we have $n+1=n+gd \Rightarrow 1=gd$.

This is a contradiction! We are given $d>1$ and we have defined $g$ as a natural number, so $gd>1$, which contradicts our result $gd=1$.

Thus, for all $d>1$ and natural $n$ if $d$ divides $n$ then $d$ does not divide $n+1$.

Comment: thanks for wonderful explanation, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If $d$ divides $n+1$ as well

$d$ must divide  $1\cdot(n+1)+(-1)\cdot n$

Comment: I'm now following that, could you please elaborate .

Comment: @NikhilMehral, We have derived that $d$ must divide $n+1-n=1,$ right? Which integer($>1$) can divide $1$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $d|n$, and let $n=\alpha d$. Also assume $d|(n+1)$ and let $(n+1)=\beta d$. So $\alpha d + 1=\beta d$, and so $d(\beta-\alpha)=1$. But as $d\gt1$, this is impossible.